# How to use Docker Swarm On Mesos?

Tags: docker, mesos, docker-swarm

I am looking for a accessible guide which explains how to use docker-swarm on Mesos (as explained in some detail in the [Docker Swarm on Mesos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUViQAu2Bw0) video).

Do I need to install a DCOS of Mesosphere? Or do I just need Mesos Master, some slaves with Mesos and Docker and then execute the steps described in https://github.com/docker/swarm/blob/master/cluster/mesos/README.md?

It is not clear to me if I need to setup all the swarm-participants in a classic swarm-way or if it is enough with the swarm manager.

As far as I understood there are no extra steps to execute on the Docker-engines in the slaves.

[image]

Comment: that's what I've posted

Answer (score 0):

The DCOS of mesosphere is not necessary, you can build/start swarm on Mesos directly. Only Swarm, Mesos cluster & Docker engine is necessary. Here's my tips (http://www.k82.me/tech/2015/11/21/swarm_mesos_integration/) about "Swarm on Mesos", please let me know if any more questions.

Comment: at least it is starting with "docker run -d -p 4375:2375 -p 3375:3375 --name=swarm-manager swarm manage -c mesos-experimental --cluster-opt mesos.address=127.0.0.1 --cluster-opt mesos.port=3375 a.b.c.d:5050" but i get no offers

Comment: added a screenshot of the logs, it looks like mesos tries to send the offers. the log-pattern you can see repeats (send offer, connect, diconnect)